# Trying to use pdf-lib to fill pdf form fields. Trouble Flattening and Saving Form

Tags: javascript, json, pdf, pdf-form

I'm looking into using the pdf-lib library form manipulating pdf forms.  The package is located here:  https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib

Edited the question yet again (it has been here for months and no takers on 2 bounties for 100) to just include a code snippet that is at least partially working after getting the right script tag libraries.

The issue I am having is that I want to be able to **Flatten and Save the form after any online editing after the pre-populated form is edited and completed.**

Here is a bit of a sample from what I have posted as an issue on Github in the pdf-lib repo here https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/965

```
$("#flatten").on("click", function(e) {

async function Flatten() {

 pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(document.getElementById('pdf').src)
 form = pdfDoc.getForm()
 form.updateFieldAppearances();
  checkboxes.forEach(function (item, index) {
    checkBox = form.getCheckBox(item);
    checkBox.defaultUpdateAppearances()
  });
 form.flatten()
 pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true })
 document.getElementById('pdf').src = pdfBytes
}

Flatten();
});
    
    
$("#pdf").on("load", function(e) {
  autoResize($(this));
});
    
function autoResize(iframe) {
    
  // iframe.height($(iframe).contents().find('html').height());
  iframe.height("1650px");
  iframe.width("1275px");
  iframe.show();
}
    
        
$("#saveform").on("click", function(e) {
    download(document.getElementById('pdf').src, SaveAs+'.pdf', "application/pdf");
});

$("#sendform").on("click", function(e) {
    alert(document.getElementById('pdf').src);
    //download(document.getElementById('pdf').src, SaveAs+'.pdf', "application/pdf");
});
```

**There is an archive.zip attached to the GitHub issue post.  If you are interested, I suggest you put the two files there on a server to see what the issue is.**  It is setup to just work if you put the test.html file and the PDF on a webserver in the same directory (root of server) and then just open it up in a browser.  If you type something into a field and then try to Flatten you'll be asked to stay on page or leave.  That is what I want to try to fix.

Comment: What is your backend tech?  I use a backend library to flatten docs after they are done in the front end.

Comment: @TJSherrill  I do use fpdi and some other php packages to populate pdf forms with data on the backend, but that one uses x/y coordinate to position fields, and I know there are other php packages to populate pdf's with form fields.  This library:  https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib is nice, but the issue I'm having with it described in my issue link noted above, namely if I edit what is in a field via the web interface, I cannot then flatten the form with the edited data preserved.  I think it just not support that feature.

Comment: @TJSherrill  The maintainers comment was "I'm not aware of a way to get a user's changes out of an iframe in the first place. PDF editing in-browser is a much sought after capability that doesn't really exist atm. The closest thing you'll find is https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js. Some folks use a combination of that with pdf-lib to implement their apps."